# Call to a member function createToken() on null?

Tags: laravel, restful-authentication

When I used the passport package , I encountered this error

> Call to a member function createToken() on null

Why do I get this error?

This is my code :

```
$users = Users::where('Email' , $username)
              ->where( 'Password' , $password)
              ->where('UserStatus' , config('global.active'))
              ->first();

if($users) {
    $success['token'] =  $users->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
} else {
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
}
```

Comment: Does `Auth::user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken` gives you problem?

Comment: If `$user` is null it meas that it probably guest (not logged).

Comment: Just remove `$user = Auth::user();` and change `$users` to $user`

Answer (score 5):

`$user = Auth::user();` is unnecessary and is what is causing your error.

```
$user = Users::where('Email' , $username)->where( 'Password' , $password)->where('UserStatus' , config('global.active'))->first();
if($user){
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
}else{
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$users` were null, there's no way that part of the control structure where `createToken` is getting called would be reached.  I wonder if this is a red herring, and there's some middleware at work here.  There are actually three instances of a method by that same name, and the namespace in your error message is notable absent there:

- /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
- /vendor/laravel/passport/src/ApiTokenCookieFactory.php
- /vendor/laravel/passport/src/HasApiTokens.php

That last one is a trait being used by the User model, and is the one you're calling.  But I'm wondering if that error is actually coming from one of the other two.  Check your error-log, probably in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`, and see if there's a stack-trace that might lend a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do other way around to make it work.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



public function authenticate(Request $request)
{


    // add UserStatus logic here if any

    if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $request->username, 'Password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) 
    {

     $user = Auth::user();
     $success['token'] =  $request->user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

     return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);

    }
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
}
```